# Displaying From field in OWA 2007 new message

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, outlook-web-access

How can I display the "From" text field when I create a new message with Outlook Web Access 2007?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the **Options** tab of the ribbon (when editing an email), there's a **Fields** section that lets you show/hide the **From** and BCC fields.

Answer (score 1):

The question was "How can I display the "From" text field when I create a new message with **Outlook Web Access 2007?**."

The solution you provided was for the *Outlook 2007 client*, not OWA.

Unfortunately, there is no option to add the "From" field in OWA 2007. This feature is now available in Exchange 2010 though.